# Cannot change file ownership from Vagrant VM

Tags: linux, permissions, vagrant, puppet, nfs

I have been using NFS mounts in my Vagrant VM for months without any problems running our puppet provisioning. As you can know each time you **create folder using puppet you have to specify its owner and group** otherwise defaults are used. We have set **default to root:root** for some reason and this is **applied to some other files / directories as well**.

Puppet trying to `chown` file to **root:root** and it **fails** but it should not because **chown exits with 0** without changing the owner or group. This behavior is same on NFS and VirtualBox Share but **puppet fails only when using NFS** share.

The question is - is there any reasonable explanation why puppet has started to fail on changing ownership of files? It used to work for months and I'm still running the same version of **Vagrant** and **VirtualBox**.

I have found a lot of questions regarding similar problem (changing ownership) and found it is ok that owner and group is not changed. I just don't know **why puppet fails because of this only on NFS**.

#### Vagrantfile mount section

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../puppet", "/root/puppet", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["rw", "tcp", "fsc", "nolock", "noacl", "async"], nfs_udp: false
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/media/src/project", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["rw", "tcp", "fsc", "nolock", "noacl", "async"], nfs_udp: false
```

#### Puppet log on NFS

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1471704237'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Farm_tooling::Webgrind/Exec[configure]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ulozto::Web::Lab/File[/media/src/ulozto/.local/]/owner: owner changed '501' to 'root'
Error: Failed to set group to '0': Operation not permitted @ lchown_internal - /media/src/ulozto/.local
Error: /Stage[main]/Ulozto::Web::Lab/File[/media/src/ulozto/.local/]/group: change from dialout to root failed: Failed to set group to '0': Operation not permitted @ lchown_internal - /media/src/ulozto/.local
```

#### Puppet log on VirtualBox share

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1471704248'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Farm_tooling::Webgrind/Exec[configure]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ulozto::Web::Lab/File[/media/src/ulozto/.local/]/owner: owner changed 'vagrant' to 'root'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ulozto::Web::Lab/File[/media/src/ulozto/.local/]/group: group changed 'vagrant' to 'root'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ulozto::Pornfile::Remote/File[/var/www/pornfile-web/PornFile/App]/owner: owner changed 'vagrant' to 'root'
```

#### Directory listing after puppet run on NFS

```
drwxr-xr-x  4  501 dialout    136 Aug 19 05:40 .local
```

I actually do not know what dialout is but 501 is ID of my account - `uid=501(northys)`. After puppet run owner is still the same.

#### Directory listing after puppet run on VirtualBox share

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant    136 Aug 19 05:40 .local
```

After puppet run owner and group is still `vagrant:vagrant` but puppet didn't fail on changing it like in NFS mount case.

Comment: Puppet log claims that the group permissions on that nfs mount are not what you think they are.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to fix it? I swear I'm using the same configuration for months so I'm really confused why it has stopped working.

Comment: The puppet logs claim that the nfs mount directory of `/var/www/project/Lorem/App` is owned by a group `dialout` and not `root`. This discounts your claim that it is owned by the `root` group. Why it is that the directory has the group `dialout` I cannot guess from the information provided. Why it is that puppet cannot change the group permission is probably because it was not mounted with that capability allowed. I have to speculate on some of this given the information provided.

Comment: I claimed that we have set root:root as default for manipulating (creating, moving...) files with puppet not that all files are owned by **root:root** - little misunderstanding, sorry. I tried both NFS and VirtualBox Share now and all files are owned by **vagrant:vagrant**, never changed and puppet just ignores it - this is what am I asking. Why is it okay that changing owner to root fails on share but not okay when fails on NFS? I have added more information to question.

Comment: Well then this is a nfs filesystem versus nfs mount permissions question. If this was puppet/vagrant then I could help, but nfs filesystem versus mount permissions is more of a sysadmin thing. Sorry.

Comment: When I asked our sysadmin team they just said it is weird and they had no idea why it does no working. Mount options listed in my config are exactly the same as my colleague has on his ubuntu-running machine. He has also troubles with this and this helped him. Now I have to run using virtualbox share which is about 100 times slower and... meh. Thank you anyway for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this here
https://serverfault.com/questions/487862/vagrant-os-x-host-nfs-share-permissions-error-failed-to-set-owner-to-1000

In my VagrantFile, I added this to the mapping to get it to work:

```
:linux__nfs_options => ["no_root_squash"], :map_uid => 0, :map_gid => 0
```